# How to implement a moving average in C without a buffer?

Tags: filters, c, moving-average

Is it possible to implement a moving average in C without the need for a window of samples?

I've found that I can optimize a bit, by choosing a window size that's a power of two to allow for bit-shifting instead of dividing, but not needing a buffer would be nice.  Is there a way to express a new moving average result only as a function of the old result and the new sample?

Define an example moving average, across a window of 4 samples to be:

```
ma <= (a + b + c + d) / 4
```

Add new sample e:

```
ma_new <= (a + b + c + d) / 4 - (a / 4) + (e / 4)
ma_new(ma, oldest_sample, new_sample) <= ma - (a / 4) + (e / 4)
```

Comment: In general, I have found the GNU Scientific Library to give useful hints for numerical tasks like this one. The ["Running Statistics" section](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/rstat.html#running-statistics) and [`rstat_add` code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gsl.git;a=blob;f=rstat/rstat.c;h=0808622876e1a4cc955857022f6d080826e61666;hb=refs/heads/master#l69) led me to the [Welford Algorithm](https://nullbuffer.com/articles/welford_algorithm.html#welfords_algorithm) & [this](https://nestedsoftware.com/2018/03/20/calculating-a-moving-average-on-streaming-data-5a7k.22879.html).

Answer (score 13):

A moving average can be implemented recursively, but for an exact computation of the moving average you have to remember the oldest input sample in the sum (i.e. the `a` in your example). For a length $N$ moving average you compute:

$$y[n]=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=n-N+1}^nx[k]\tag{1}$$

where $y[n]$ is the output signal and $x[n]$ is the input signal. Eq. (1) can be written recursively as

$$y[n]=y[n-1]+\frac{1}{N}(x[n]-x[n-N])\tag{2}$$

So you always need to remember the sample $x[n-N]$ in order to compute (2).

As pointed out by Conrad Turner, you can use an (infinitely long) exponential window instead, which allows you to compute the output only from the past output and the current input:

$$y[n]=\alpha x[n]+(1-\alpha)y[n-1]\tag{3}$$

but this is not a standard (unweighted) moving average but an exponentially weighted moving average, where samples further in the past get a smaller weight, but (at least in theory) you never forget anything (the weights just get smaller and smaller for samples far in the past).

Comment: Your first method is exactly that in tarabyte's original post, but they did not want to maintain a buffer and this does require a buffer of length N, holding the values in the current moving average.

Comment: @ConradTurner: That's right. I wanted to show that for any $N$ you always need the sample $x[n-N]$, otherwise you can't do the standard moving average, recursive or not. The exponential moving average could be an option, but it's a different thing. It all depends on what the OP wants.

Answer (score 11):

What is wrong with a fading memory ([exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)) moving average:

```
ma_new = alpha * new_sample + (1-alpha) * ma_old
```

Comment: Let me count the ways: 1) it's not a moving average (it's auto-regressive). 2) It's not finite (duration) impulse response. 3) It can never be linear phase (like an FIR can).  On the plus side: 1) it's ludicrously simple, 2) It works in many practical applications, and 3) it meets the OP's requirement for no buffer.  Plus one, by the way. :-)

Comment: Its not being a moving average really is a matter of terminology many references do describe it as such (not just Wikipedia). Terminology varies from application domain to application domain also.

Comment: The fact is: mathematically, it's not a moving average (all zero) filter. Wikipedia may say so; that doesn't make it so.

Comment: @PeterK.: Well, it moves, and it computes a (weighted) average. So 'exponentially weighted moving average' does actually make sense (to me).

Comment: +2 to the number names I've seen allocated to that.  I've heard it called a leaky-integrator, low-pass filter, FIR filter and now exponential moving average and fading memory moving average.

Comment: @tarabyte It's *definitely not* a FIR filter. It *is* a variety of IIR filter.

Comment: @PeterK. I think MattL is completely correct.  Semantically and practically.  Weighted averages are still averages.  Just not the simple average where every sample in the average is weighted equally.  But as long as the weighting coefficients add to one, it's still an average.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yup, I agreed with Matt seven and a half years ago (but only by upvoting). :-)

Comment: got it.  Matt used an extremely simple and persuasive refute to your claim that it wasn't moving average.  Once in a while Matt and I **might** lock horns on something, but, for the most part, I agree with Matt technically on just about everything I read from him.

Answer (score 2):

code for (3) above , simple recursive filter $y(n)=αx(n) + (1-α)y(n-1)$. Where $α<1$ . The smaller $α$ the smoother the filter. I use it to smooth a data stream with no buffers.

```
uint32 filter(uint32 x, uint32 y)
{
    return (x + 9*y) / 10;  //( α=1/10 )
}

main()
{
  angle = filter(new_angle,angle);   // y(n) = filter( x(n), y(n-1) )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method gives you an approximation of the moving average by basically assuming that the value of the sample `window_size` samples ago is equal to the previous moving average, which is updated every `window_size` samples.

It works well if your values are randomly distributed, but outliers will skew it more than the exact moving average.

Here's some "pseudo-code" in Python syntax. Note that `enumerate(samples)` just means: "Get all the samples in order" and doesn't imply that there *has* to be a buffer (but it will indeed work if you feed it a buffer). The implementation in C is substantially longer.

```
previous_average = 0
total = 0
for count, sample in enumerate(samples):
    if count % window_size == 0: # Update previous_average every window_size samples
        previous_average = total/window_size
    total += sample
    if count > window_size:
        total -= previous_average
    current_average = total/window_size
```

With the 4 point example we can estimate the error:

$\begin{align}
y_n = \frac{(a + b + c + d)}{4} &, y_{n+1} = \frac{(a+b+c+d)}{4} + \frac{e}{4} - \frac{a}{4} \\
y*_{n+1} &= \frac{(a + b + c + d) - y_{n} + e}{4} \\
&= \frac{(a+b+c+d)}{4} - \frac{(a+b+c+d)}{16} + \frac{e}{4} \\
&= \frac{3(a+b+c+d)}{16} + \frac{e}{4} \\
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
E &= y*_{n+1} - y_{n+1} \\
  &= \frac{3a}{16} - \frac{a+b+c+d}{16}
\end{align}$

I am lazily going to assume that with an arbitrary window size $W$

$\begin{align}
E &= \frac{(W-1)a}{W^2} - \frac{y_n}{W} \\
\end{align}$

If $W$ is large enough, then:

$\begin{align}
E &\approx \frac{a - y_n}{W}
\end{align}$

Which is the residual of point $a$ divided by the total number of residuals...

This is just an approximation of the error for the first `count % window_size == 0` iteration, and I'm already trying to go further than my maths abilities, but since we can start at any $x_n = a$ it suggests that as long as $W$ is sufficiently large or each $x_{n} - y_{n}$ is sufficiently small then this average will produce the same average residual as a fit with the exact formula.

I've attached an image from my test script showing the exact 100 point moving average compared to this method:

[image: Comparison of exact moving average with this method]

Comment: Please don't hate me if this method is garbage but I tested it with Python's `random.random` and it worked...

Comment: Update: in my use case we did end up deciding this method was garbage

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for what reasons did you end up deciding this method was garbage?

Comment: @Slater The overall error is not large and the signal has the correct shape, but the locations, number, and heights of the peaks in the signal are very different.

Answer (score 1):

````
#define COEF 32

uint32_t filter(uint32_t raw)
{
    static uint64_t accum = 0;
    accum = accum - accum / COEF + raw;
    return accum/COEF;
}
```
````

Comment: Can be modified for signed values. Make sure M_COEF is not too large.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a moving average without individual item memory for a GPS tracking program I wrote.

I start with 1 sample and divide by 1 to get the current avg.

I then add anothe sample and divide by 2 to the the current avg.

This continues until I get to the length of the average.

Each time afterwards, I add in the new sample, get the average and remove that average from the total.

I am not a mathematician but this seemed like a good way to do it.  I figured it would turn the stomach of a real math guy but, it turns out it is one of the accepted ways of doing it.  And it works well.  Just remember that the higher your "length" the slower it is following what you want to follow.  That may not matter most of the time but when following satellites, if you are slow, the trail could be far from the actual position and it will look bad. You could have a gap between the sat and the trailing dots. I chose a length of 15 updated 6 times per minute to get adequate smoothing and not get too far from the actual sat position with the smoothed trail dots.

Comment: it's not a moving average

Answer (score 0):

Instigated by the szmoore answer [1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/50660/55891)

What is the best approximation to a moving average of length $W$ with an estimator?

$\mu_{k+1} = a \mu_{k} + b x_{k+1}$

With $a=1-\alpha$, $b=\alpha$, we get to the repeatedly mentioned exponentially weighted moving average
[2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/20336/55891),
[3](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/20342/55891)
[4](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/73075/55891), with $\alpha=1/W$ we end up with [1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/50660/55891) (except for the complications added to the algorithm).

**Steady state performance**
For a step signal we expect $\mu_{k} = x_k$, let's assume $x_k = C$. Then we have $C = a C + b C$, i.e. $a = 1-b$, so we can restate the equation as $\mu_{k+1} = (\mu_k - x_{k+1}) a$, so the parameterization

**Immediate response**: Suppose an impulsive $x$, where $x_{k}=C$, and $x_j=0$ for $j \ne k$, then the average $\mu_{k+1}=C/W$, this requires $\alpha = 1/W$.

At this point I was satisfied that I was able to defend that answer as the optimal solution in some aspects. But then I noted that he was doing some complicated stuff there, combining some subsampling and exponential averaging, and actually did not satisfy the "no-buffer" requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure where the buffer in my answer came from; the embedded implementation required a running total, a previous average, and the current average. The `enumerate(samples)` I showed in Python may be misleading.
I never actually found a better solution; we just deleted a whole bunch of other unrelated buffers and made space to do the traditional moving average that way.